# How to make wkhtmltopdf faux bold same as Google Chrome faux bold (or atleast similar)

Tags: css, wkhtmltopdf

I have a font that only exists in normal (400) font weight. However I have made it bold by using font-weight: bold;

This looks great in the browser, but when I use wkhtmltopdf it only display it in the normal, 400 font-weight. Anyone know how to make wkhtmltopdf be able to do Faux Bold just like browsers can?

EDIT:
After additional research I find out that actually wkhtmltopdf IS doing it bold, however just very very slightly compared to browsers such as Google Chrome. Is there any way I can control how "bold" something should become by using font-weight: bold;? Please note that the font only have normal (400) font weight, so I'm looking to do a faux bold.

So it would be great if I could force it to make it "more" bold in wkhtmltopdf, so it makes same as in for example Google Chrome.

Comment: Can you control what CSS is used in wkhtmltopdf and what in Chrome? If so, there might be a way using alternate definitions

Comment: having a similar issue while using wicked-pdf which internally uses wkhtmlltox

Comment: I still have not found a solution to this. I would think that since wkhtmltopdf is using Webkit Engine, it should be able to present the faux bolds in a similar way as the webkit browsers.